# Send SMS From Rails Hobo App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, twilio, hobo

I'm new to Hobo, I want to send SMS(Twilio would be great as I have already worked with it in Rails) to a user when he signs up, i.e. user fills out the sign up form with phone field and when he hits the submit button a SMS containing a Verification Code will be sent to his entered phone number and email.

I can do this in Rails but have no idea how to do this in Hobo. Any kind off help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hobo looks like it just generates a Rails application, can you not add Twilio integration as you normally would? (Sorry, I haven't played with hobo before, so I don't know about it in any more depth.)

Comment: Exactly, Hobo just adds some nice extras to help you build Rails apps faster. But adding Twilio should be exactly the same as in a vanilla Rails application. Are you encountering any Hobo specific issue?